# Cross-domain iframe w/ proxy doesn't load external server resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, iframe

I am working on a project and need to use `iframes` for retrieving the content of another website. I am using the NPM module `request` for getting the website contents and sending it back just normally, with vanilla Node.js for returning the results. My problem is, tens of websites returns their websites like this:

```
<script src="foo.js">
<script src="../../bar.css">
```

So, when I get the results, it starts looking for those files in my server, which is my problem.

How can I **convert** a `stylesheet href` or `script src` from:

```
foo.js 
bar.css
```

to

```
//example.com/foo.js
```

or

```
//example.com/bar.css
```

Any solution or workaround is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Easy, take the domain you stole the content from as well as the path and use it to generate the correct path. Dont forget to check for the base tag!

Comment: For example, if the path is `//example.com/foo/bar` and the script tag is `<script src="foo.js">` and there is no base tag, then you know the path to the script is `//example.com/foo/bar/foo.js`

Comment: for web scraping there is no easy work-around. You have to replace the resource with the domain information + resource as above example...